# Tailwind CSS and ASP.Net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, npm, webpack, webforms, tailwind-css

I have been tasked with styling an ASP.Net Web Forms application - the development part is being handled by a senior developer. I would like to use Tailwind CSS to style it, in order to take advantage of its capabilities to speed up the process.

Here's where the problem starts... would the usual npm way of installing it work with ASP.Net Web Forms? I'm afraid I'll run into building issues with webpack and so on. I get that Web Forms is basically considered deprecated, but the development tools had been decided before I could have any say.

If it wouldn't work, is there any workaround?

Comment: A suggestion here, remove the tailwind-css tag and be more specific is the issue with tailwind tooling or with webpack? also share some code/versions, etc. So people can actually see where the issue might be.

Comment: Hello, it's more an inquiry rather than an issue - I'm asking how to install Tailwind CSS in Web Forms as I'm not sure how to do it without generating a bunch of build issues. I haven't done any testing yet as I'm not exactly sure where to start - I've only used Tailwind with Vue.js and Angular.js before

Comment: That is not very helpful, it seems to be a very specific use case, if you don't provide what you have tried or don't try yourself I doubt anyone will have any guidance for you. My suggestion is that you use the CLI instead for this type of project.

Comment: Turns out PowerShell can play command prompt in this case and the CLI works just fine

Comment: I don't get it, you can run the CLI anywhere you don't even need to install the package. But happy that it works for you.

Comment: Well, because, you know, the CLI is based on Node.js... I had no idea how that would mix with ASP.net etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question: Npm packages can be installed using PowerShell in Visual Studio. It's an odd hybrid and definitely not best practice (neither is Web Forms!), but it does the job just fine.